# What is the fundamental difference between Matrix<TDepth> and Mat in EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

- Why is `Mat` not enough in EmguCV?
- Why can't `Matrix<>` load an image from a file itself?

For instance,

```
Mat img = new Mat(path);
```

is a valid operation. But,

```
Matrix<byte> img = new Matrix<byte>(path);
```

or,

```
Matrix<byte> img = Matrix<byte>.FromFile(path);
```

aren't valid operations.

Comment: A lot of those "extra" classes look either like things wrapping legacy things, or convenience for working in managed environment. I think that in most cases a `Mat` is good enough if you want to take most advantage of OpenCV itself. Generally having to access individual pixels directly is a bit of an anti-pattern (you're missing out on all the optimized OpenCV functionality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information from the [Emgu Wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) the fundamental difference between the two types is whether the underlying data array is managed or not.

`Mat` is a wrapper around the C++ [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) class. Generally this class acts as a smart pointer which manages the memory allocated for the data array it owns (although it's able to just observe as well -- a good example of this capability is the ability to return a `Mat` header for a [`Matrix`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.3/document/html/ec1c8c3f-a99c-a082-e794-bb74db961c60.htm) instance in C#). This means that OpenCV is able to (re)allocate the memory as necesssary. The trade-off is that in such cases it's [more difficult](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#The_fastest_way_with_no_memory_copy_required._Be_caution.21.21.21) to access the underlying data effectively in C#.

The `Matrix` class uses a managed array to hold the data. That means you can easily access the underlying data array in C#.

Honestly, the best person to tell you why it's not possible to load `Matrix` from an image file would be the author. My guess would be that it's intended to represent other things than images. Technically this could be added in the same way as the ability to load an image file was given to the `Mat` wrapper (the C++ equivalent has no such feature).